# convert data64 images to jpg

Tags: file, post, base64, temporary-files

I've a small problem, the code below fetches POST URLs, and uploads it as a random file,
would much prefer to use $uriPhp on the fly, unfortunately sometimes the data:image/png;base64 is very large, and gives the follow error sometimes.

ERROR:
ResponseText: Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

$_POST['url'] would be;;

data:image/png;base64,Vleornyg...OR...data:image/jpeg;base64=

whats the best way to stop the error? no problems with jpg,png,gif,jpeg.
the error only occurs with data:image/png;base64,{very long binary data}

would appreciate if someone could help me out, thanks in advance

```
if(isset($_POST['url'])) { if(substr($_POST['url'], 0, 4) == "data") 
$uriPhp = 'data://' . substr($_POST['url'], 5);
else $uriPhp = $_POST['url'];

$image_data = file_get_contents($uriPhp);

$tmpfile = tempnam("/home/web/httdocs/uploads/",'img');
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $image_data);
$jpg_data =shell_exec("convert $tmpfile jpg:-");
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $jpg_data);
```